# やっぱりお前はさぁ…っ、こんなにも、こんなにもさぁ…

Tags: translation

> やっぱりお前はさぁ…っ、こんなにも、こんなにもさぁ…

My translation: After all you are...., so much, so much

What was this guy trying to say? Or is it incomplete on purpose? Even with context I don't get it.
I would like to know if there's something I haven't seen and that's the reason my translation is bad and everything actually makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's an incomplete sentence similar to "You... what a ..." or "You're such a ...". This is not an idiomatic expression with a hidden meaning that would surprise you. こんなにも is an adverbial expression similar to *this* as in *this big*, and thus some adjective is missing after it.

The unsaid part purely depends on the context. I don't know why the guy is so deeply impressed by お前. If you also don't know why, that probably means you are not following the story correctly.